# grease pencil rig+ stroke getting messed up

Tags: rigging, armature, 2d

I am trying to rig a grease pencil drawing , everything is working as the set weights except the arm it is getting weirdly distorted when I am trying to move it. Any help is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Ra5NSKqE" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Ra5NSKqE/)

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance it looks like you've assigned the same vertex to multiple bones so you're getting multiple movements.Try assigning the hand just to the hand bone and remove from the arm etc.

From my experience with Grease Pencil weight painting seems to only apply a 1 or 0 in 2D as opposed to actual weights unfortunately (I'm currently in an experimental build so may just be the version I'm in).

Hope that helps
Matt